# Linux Mint 17.1 Cinnamon is slower in computer than in Virtual Box

Tags: linux-mint, performance, ati

After some months working in a VirtualBox VM with Linux Mint (the host as a Windows 7), I've finally installed Mint 17.1 Cinnamon on the same computer.

And the experience hasn't been good. The fact is that running Mint directly, bare to the metal, is slower than running Mint thru VirtualBox, on a Windows 7 host...

I imagine, I'm not sure, that the problem is in my video card (an ATI Radeon 5450). The computer is fast enough (AMD Athlon X3 450, 6Gb RAM, a simple SATA HD), but it seems that neither the open source x.org drivers nor the fglrx drivers are performant enough.

And my question is, what can I do to make Mint 17.1 usable in my computer?

Comment: Please give more information about your experience in question. What do you mean exactly by slower?

Comment: It's a bit difficul to explain... The first thing I noticed is that window movement (when you move it around the screen) is a bit jerky, scrolling a site like this in firefox is also jerky, etc... And, in the virtual machine, scrolling with firefox is completly smooth, as window movement

Comment: I suspect that Cinnamon has detected that you had potential acceleration, and therefore has activated some graphical effects which it didn't inside the virtual machine. I don't know how that's configured in Cinnamon, but look at the settings and try to deactivate the fancier effects, in particular any 3D stuff.

Comment: @Gilles: But this graphics card has acceleration! Maybe this isn't working correctly?

Comment: Accelerated fancy effects may well be slower than non-accelerated non-fancy effects. Especially if the drivers aren't perfect, and given that GPU makers don't consider Linux users worth spending money on and often actively hinder Linux driver writers by not giving out hardware specifications, GPU drivers for Linux tend to be subpar compared to Windows.